# What's the most secure way to use facebook login system api

Tags: php, facebook, security, facebook-graph-api

The only way users can log into my site is by using facebook login (I use php sdk). I store their email, id, content their create in my db.

I am using CodeIgniter and let them have access to pages based on their facebook user id which is stored in a session variable. I am wondering if that's secure enough. If it's not, what would be most secure way to do it?

Comment: are you using ssl on your site? If not, it is not secure. Session IDs can still be hijacked...

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever store personal data in SESSION or COOKIE.

I recommend that, only store your members' member ID, not Facebook ID. Then pull other data from database by using it.